# nextauth with prisma adapter never sets client session

Tags: prisma, next-auth

ok, so I have followed every example and clone every sample project I can find from nextauth and prisma about using the adapter for oauth (github etc) logins.  It works perfectly for grabbing the auth data prob github let's say and properly created the account, session, and user in my database.  HOWEVER, in the SessionProvider, the session value is always undefined.  so calling useSession() in child pages is useless.  The interesting (yet very wrong way to go about this) thing is... using getServerSideProps and calling getSession() properly returns the logged in user's session info from the database.  Pulling my hair out.  All the examples I tried (sample code) responds the same way.  1 or 2 other users on stack said they got excited that getServerSideProps works, but why should I have to do that on EVERY page just to get a session when one clearly exists in the client cache since it looks it up with the id from the database. I find it really hard to believe they all just... well recent versions just don't work anymore (I did find one that works, but it is using like 2-3 yr old versions of nextauth and prisma... not my choice for a solution either).

here is my relevant code:

```
// _app.ts
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
      <SessionProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </AuthProvider>
      </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default App
```

my auth callback

```
// api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
const authHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
export default authHandler;

const options = {
    providers: [
        GitHubProvider({
            // @ts-ignore
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            // @ts-ignore
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
};
```

and finally my prisma.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

// I also tried setting this global since ts was complaining about not seeing it defined
// but having a. pre-named global for this helped nothing except ts checking to shut up
// declare global {
//    var prisma:PrismaClient
//}

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!global.prisma) {
        // @ts-ignore
        global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

I have tried all slight variations I have found but nothing produces a client session.  All the db stuff works great... just no sessions are every created in the SessionProvider.

Praying someone will read this with a true solution and not just "ahh... just use the workaround" LOL.  Thanks everyone for taking a look at my dilemma. Hope you can help!